# Как исправить ошибку Line magic function `%matplotlib.inline` not found после установки Anaconda 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, установка, anaconda

Здравствуйте подскажите как исправить ошибку:

```
ERROR:root:Line magic function `%matplotlib.inline` not found.
```

После установки пакета **Anaconda3-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86** в Windows 7 (x86), браузер Firefox 51.0.1 (32-бит).
Ошибка возникает после установки пакета, открытия **Anaconda Promt** и вызова оттуда **ipython notebook** в командной строке.

Для проверки правильной работы пакета после установки вводил эти тестовые данные в ipython notebook:

```
%matplotlib.inline
from numpy import linspace, cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = cos(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

по идее должен появиться график, а выходит ошибка.

Программа **Spyder** и **Anaconda Navigator** из пакета **Anaconda3-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86** также не запускаются.

все эти файлы которые не импортируются:
*C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py
C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py
C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py
C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py
C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py
C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py
C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py*

находятся в папке созданной по умолчанию инсталятором Anaconda3-4.3.0.1-Windows-x86:
**C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib**

изменил название папки с **Lib** на **lib**:
**C:\Users\DmitrOK71\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib**

но это не помогло решить проблему, появляется всё та же ошибка:
**ERROR:root:Line magic function `%matplotlib.inline` not found.**

не только в браузере **Firefox 51.0.1 (32-бит)**, но так же и в **Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (32-бит)** и в **Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18449 (32-бит)**

Comment: точку уберите в `%matplotlib.inline` (на пробел замените)

Comment: это не помогает, хотя сообщение о том что магическая функция не найдена не появляется, сообщения об ошибке импорта остаются те же самые ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура. Не помогает также замена команды %matplotlib.inline на %matplotlib notebook

Comment: это *помогает* (я поверял), но решает только **одну** проблему. У вас их *несколько*. В частности, не следует руками папки переименовывать. Удалите полностью текущую установку anaconda, Python. И поставьте с нуля (переименовывание папок руками НЕ является частью установки) — но установка anaconda на Windows это *отдельный* вопрос от  `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: удалил установленную Anaconda через её же Uninstall-Anaconda, перезагрузил ПК (на всякий случай), установил заново с нуля. Все пункты по умолчанию. Ни эта функция %matplotlib.inline ни %matplotlib inline не работают (у меня). Пишут что такое было в старых версиях IPython, а версии IPython >=1.0 не имеют такой проблемы. У меня установлены по сообщению из conda list - ipython 5.1.0 py36_0 и jupyter 1.0.0 py36_3. Папку я переименовал уже после того как проявилась ошибка, прочитал что эта ошибка может быть из-за неправильного пути установки (path) здесь:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175798

Comment: т.к. с Anaconda у меня ничего не получилось пришлось её удалить и поставить другой пакет WinPython-32bit-3.5.3.0Qt5. Там правда сразу говорят для установки WinPython, пользователям Windows 7/8 возможно придётся установить Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, что я также сделал. Результат: функция %matplotlib.inline -также выдаёт ошибку - ERROR:root:Line magic function `%matplotlib.inline` not found. А вот изменённая команда с пробелом вместо точки %matplotlib notebook вполне работает и тестовый  пример запущенный в Jupyter notebook рисует двумерный график как и задумано

Comment: Ещё лучше вместо %matplotlib.inline в Jupyter Notebook при установке из пакета WinPython-32bit-3.5.3.0Qt5 работает команда %matplotlib notebook. Появляются дополнительные интерактивные элементы выше и ниже графика и наведении курсора на график (чего нет с %matplotlib inline). Вот тестовый пример для проверки работы: %matplotlib notebook
from numpy import linspace, cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = cos(x)
plt.plot(x, y)