# Python import mpi4py.MPI as mpi

Tags: python, mpi

Всем добрый вечер,

Я установил себе библиотеку **mpi4py** при вводе в интерпретаторе строки
`import mpi4py.MPI` мне выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexey\Dropbox\LBM\code2016\python\palabos\3d\lol.py", line 18, in <module>
    import mpi4py.MPI
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура.
```

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь с этой проблемой?

Comment: Вот тебе [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630951/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-line-magic-function-matplotlib-inline-not-found-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81) на похожий вопрос там тоже связанно с anaconda3 и такая же ошибка а из моих рекомендаций переустанови python. И да ещё вот эта [ссылка](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1866055.html) там обсуждают проблему с установкой mpi4py.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ответам в [этом](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mpi4py/VA7Aihi64R0/xG8AbTtOCgAJ) топике
нужно сделать следующее:

1. Удалить OpenMPI
2. Удалить mpi4py
3. Установить Microsoft MPI
4. Переустановить mpi4py с галочкой "Установить двоичное колесо"

Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой, мне помогло.

Comment: Не ленитесь перевести свой ответ, чтобы этого не делали за Вас другие.